# How I change connection string for DataSet or LINQ when installing desktop app on different computer with different server instance?

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I created a desktop app using c#, my app use DataSet and LINQ to work with local SQL server database, new if I install this app on another computer that have another SQL server name, What should I do to change the connection string for the Dataset  and LINQ? I understand that LINQ get the connection string from my app settings but for my DataSet I don't have any idea, but I can't change connection string in settings because it's only for reading. I hope that my question is clear enough and thank for any help!

Comment: Usually connectionstrings are stored in your application config file and you can change this string with the setup process of your application. Failing that you need to use the ConnectionStringBuilder class appropriate for your database ([SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)) To get a more detailed answer you need to show some of your code where you try to use this connection string

Comment: I used in all my app because you can generate the Dataset and LINQ objects automatically using Microsoft VS.

Comment: What, besides the server name, actually changes in your connection string?  Isn't `(local)` or just a '.' enough? I'm not sure if I understand that the DB is installed on the local machine.

Comment: 1) *but for my DataSet I don't have any idea* So how should *we* have any idea? 2) *but I can't change connection string in settings because it's only for reading.* This turns your question into the (too broad) question how to provide a user-friendly way to customize a database connection when installing an app on a client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option to store connection strings in the database,this database can act like a meta data for your application.

Now when installing your application through msi you can give users the option to provide input values  using the ***[TextBoxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e04k6f53(v=vs.100).aspx)*** dialog.
User can provide different inputs using these at the time of installation.

Comment: You mean they have to connect to the database to store the connection string? Do you know the rhyme "there's a hole in the bucket"?